# NSPredicateEditor Change Control Height Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, autolayout

I can't figure out why when I run my program and press the (+) button for the default predicate control to add another row that it will not increase the size of the predicate control and push the corresponding NSOutlineView below down.

Right now what happens is it will add the rows, but I have to use the mouse wheel to scroll within the small frame, instead of the frame growing to adjust to the height of the rows.

I'm using AutoLayout, not sure if that is a problem in this case.  I believe my constraints are set correctly.  I put a constraint to ensure that the distance between the NSOutlineView and NSPredicateView would always be -1 so as the window scrolls it stays in place correctly.  I am not sure this is even the issue but doubt it at the moment.  Just letting you know I'm aware of it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FINALLY figured out the answer! Hurray!

Here is the simple answer: SetFrame DOES NOT WORK with AUTOLAYOUT!

Instead you have to edit the constraints!

This means set a constraint for 'height' on the NSPredicateEditor and IBOutlet it to your code.

Then use the following command.

```
NSInteger newRowCount = [_predicateEditor numberOfRows];
NSInteger rowHeight = [_predicateEditor rowHeight];

[[_predicateEditorHeight animator] setConstant:rowHeight*newRowCount];
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I found my auto-growing predicates editor suddenly empty after reorganizing my constraints and layouts. After some sleepless nights I found this answer. Thumb up!